# How to write a Cplex constraint for product types

Tags: optimization, cplex, opl, bin-packing

I am trying to write a constraint in Cplex that will only allow certain types of items to be packed together (recipe) in a bin. I have all my product data in a tuple with the recipes represented by either "1" "2" or "3". My code so far:

```
{string} product = ...;
 
 tuple ItemInfo {
   int width;
   float amps;
   int recipe;
   int demand;
}

ItemInfo Items[product] = ...;

 dvar boolean x[Bin][product];
 dvar boolean y[Bin];
 
 minimize sum(b in Bin) y[b];
 
 subject to {
   
forall(b in Bin) sum(j in product) Items[j].width*x[b][j] <= Width*y[b];
forall(b in Bin) sum(j in product) Items[j].amps*x[b][j] >= MinAmps*y[b];
forall(b in Bin) sum(j in product) Items[j].amps*x[b][j] <= MaxAmps*y[b]; 
forall(j in product) sum(i in Bin) x[i][j] == Items[j].demand;
 }
```

Any ideas on how to ensure there is only one recipe per bin would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

if you compute

```
{int} recipes={Items[i].recipe | i in product};
```

then you can write the constraint

```
forall(b in Bin) 1>=sum(r in recipes) (1<=sum(p in product:Items[p].recipe==r) x[b][p]);
```

which makes sure that you have max one recipe per bin

Full working example:

.mod

```
{string} product = ...;
 
 tuple ItemInfo {
   int width;
   float amps;
   int recipe;
   int demand;
}

int Width=10;
int MinAmps=0;
int MaxAmps=20;



range Bin=1..3;

ItemInfo Items[product] = ...;


{int} recipes={Items[i].recipe | i in product};


 dvar boolean x[Bin][product];
 dvar boolean y[Bin];
 
 minimize sum(b in Bin) y[b];
 
 subject to {
   
forall(b in Bin) sum(j in product) Items[j].width*x[b][j] <= Width*y[b];
forall(b in Bin) sum(j in product) Items[j].amps*x[b][j] >= MinAmps*y[b];
forall(b in Bin) sum(j in product) Items[j].amps*x[b][j] <= MaxAmps*y[b]; 
forall(j in product) sum(i in Bin) x[i][j] == Items[j].demand;

forall(b in Bin) 1>=sum(r in recipes) (1<=sum(p in product:Items[p].recipe==r) x[b][p]);

 }
```

and .dat

```
product={"A","B","C"};
Items=[<1,1,1,1>,<2,2,2,2>,<3,3,1,1>];
```